# unable to install recommendify gem - hiredis.h not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, hiredis

I am trying to install recommendify gem.

This gem try to compile a native bin called recommendify to be faster than ruby´s parser.

First i tried to install like other common gem:

```
gem install recommendify
```

and this is the error:

```
➜  ~  gem install recommendify
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing recommendify:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/villa/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb

make mkdir -p ../bin
gcc -Wall recommendify.c -lhiredis -o ../bin/recommendify
recommendify.c:4:10: fatal error: 'hiredis/hiredis.h' file not found
#include <hiredis/hiredis.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Second, i installed hiredis with brew:

```
brew install hiredis
```

and now if i search hiredis i can see:

```
➜  ~  brew list hiredis
/usr/local/Cellar/hiredis/0.11.0/include/hiredis/ (5 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/hiredis/0.11.0/lib/libhiredis.0.10.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/hiredis/0.11.0/lib/ (3 other files)
➜  ~  find /usr/local/include -name hiredis
/usr/local/include/hiredis
➜  ~  ls -al /usr/local/include/hiredis
lrwxr-xr-x  1 villa  admin  40 15 dic 12:54 /usr/local/include/hiredis -> ../Cellar/hiredis/0.11.0/include/hiredis
```

In my path is included '/usr/local/include' -> the directory when is installed hiredis:

```
➜  ~  echo $PATH
/usr/local/include:/Users/villa/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/Cellar/elixir/0.10.3/bin:/Users/villa/.rbenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance

EDIT 1 ***

I have tried with the solution of the first answer:

```
gem install recommendify -- --with-hiredis-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/hiredis/0.11.0
```

and also:

```
gem install recommendify -- --with-hiredis-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/hiredis/0.11.0/include/hiredis
```

Having in both the same error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing recommendify:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/villa/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-hiredis-dir=/usr/local/include/hiredis

make
mkdir -p ../bin
gcc -Wall recommendify.c -lhiredis -o ../bin/recommendify
recommendify.c:4:10: fatal error: 'hiredis/hiredis.h' file not found
#include <hiredis/hiredis.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

EDIT 2 ***

I have reinstalled xcode, line-command-tools and ruby with rbenv and the problem is solved. I dont know which of this three element was the problem but now it works :D

Thanks to everyone

Comment: Does mac have devel versions of packets? For example, in linux, we should do `apt-get install redis`, and then `apt-get install redis-devel` to install headers

Comment: I dont think so,i have searched in brew:

 brew search redis
hiredis  redis

Answer (score 2):

Some of *gems* are pure ruby, while others (mostly platform specific linking against existing c/c++ libraries, e. g. bindings) are written in both ruby and c/c++. The part, written in c/c++ is called `native extensions`. To compile them you need:

- build tools;
- ruby development environment;
- additional libraries/headers required by this specific gem.

In your case you seem to have first two requirements satisfied, while your system is unable to locate development files for `hiredis`. The summing up:

```
gem install recommendify -- --with-hiredis-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/hiredis/0.11.0
```

should resolve the issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is no formula called `hiredis-dev`. I tried it with `brew install hiredis` and it worked, however I am using RVM, not rbenv.

Comment: RVM is about ruby package management, it nevertheless requires development headers to build native extensions against existing library. Unfortunately I have no OSX here to check my suggestions. Would you mind to run `gem install recommendify --verbose` and append the output to your original post?

Comment: I think that RVM handles much more and tries to set your $PATH and other things correctly. It also comes with its own installation of Rubygems. Although I do not have /usr/local/include in my $PATH, RVM seems to handle this correctly.

Comment: Aha. It seems that an update in my answer should resolve an issue.

Comment: Yes, explicitly setting the location of hiredis seems like a very good idea! +1 However I think it does not solve the original problem, the OP will probably have the same problem with the next gem that has a native extension...

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu I was able to get this gem install after installing libpq-dev

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```